# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am getting this error when trying to run Monero Wallet from www.getmonero.org on my Ubuntu machine:

> $ ./start-gui.sh
>
> ./monero-wallet-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-glx.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have downloaded the "monero-gui-v0.11.1.0" wallet. I tried this with both 32 and 64 bit version.
I also installed all the required dependencies listed on https://github.com/monero-project/monero
The Ubuntu system details are:

> Description:   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>
> Linux pc 4.4.0-98-generic #121-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 14:24:03 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try: ldd monero-wallet-gui | grep xcb    then it if shows a filename, try: file INSERTTHATFILENAMEHERE

Comment: This is what I am getting:
$ ldd monero-wallet-gui |grep xcb

libxcb-glx.so.0 => not found

libX11-xcb.so.1 => not found

libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7730000)

$ file /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1: symbolic link to libxcb.so.1.1.0

Comment: You have 32 bit libs. Make sure you get a 32 bit monero-wallet-gui, and try again.

Comment: I checked again and get the same error with 32 bit too. The cli version although does not complain. How do I make the GUI work too? Thanks.

Comment: If you still get a libX11-xcb.so.1 not found, you need to install libX11-xcb.so (which I think ought to be installed already, but just in case). If it doesn't help, look for libX11-xcb.* on your disk, and run file on it.

Comment: I found libX11-xcb.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. The file command on it gives: libX11-xcb.so: symbolic link to libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
I assume that I have 32 bit version of libxcb and 64 bit version of libX11-xcb, correct? What do I do to fix it? Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Now that's weird. I know some distros install both 32 and 64 bit versions of stuff, maybe that's it. You probably want to run the 64 bit version if you have both. Then before running monero-wallet-cli: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo:bar with foo and bar being the directories where you find the 64 bit libs it finds 32 bit libs for instead. And if you don't have them installed, install them first. Though hopefully if the distro isn't braindead, installing them *should* make it work without LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on a 64 bit system and could get rid of them via:

```
sudo apt install libxcb1:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libfontconfig:i386 libx11-data:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386
```

But afterwards still a segfault happens - seems that the monero wallet gui is not (yet?) compatible with 64 bit systems.

Comment: That's really fishy. Are you using a 32 bit binary somehow ?

Comment: yes, there does not exist a 64 bit binary for monero-wallet-gui at this time, I thought I could run the 32 bit binary on a 64 bit machine

Comment: I've been running on a 64 bit machine ages ago. If they don't supply a ready made binary for your particular arch, you can build it yourself, it works fine.